# prepared mysqli statement - always returns 0 for num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

I've been working for the past hour on this one prepared statement.

It returns `0` for the `num_rows` every time.

I've run the query through my database manually in phpmyadmin and there's nothing wrong with it. And `$user_id` is set fine as well.

```
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT google_id FROM google_users WHERE google_id = ? LIMIT 1"))
{
    $statement->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    if ($statement->num_rows < 1)
    {
        $alerts .= '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Your login session was not valid. Please log in again.</div>';
    }
    $statement->free_result();
    $statement->close();
}
```

Comment: Are there any results then?

Comment: @Jite when I run it through the database it returns a google_id as expected

Comment: Is the google_id stored as a int or string in the database?

Comment: Currently decimal(21,0)....hmmm you might be onto something...what does this mean?

Comment: I'd echo the `$user_id` value and check so that its correct (could be that php cuts it of if its too big, it could be a larger number than a 64b int allows, its a google id, they quite long). Also, try change the `i` in the `bind_param` call to a `d`.

Comment: just tried all those things - still nothing - the $user id was stored fine I echoed it out to check

Comment: I changed the google_id field to an int(30) now.....still same problem with the above code

Comment: The value you set `INT` to in mysql is not the size of the integer, but the size of the column in the ui. `BIGINT` would probably be the closest you could get (which might still be too small), I would personally use a string for this (`varchar(255)`, in the varchar case, the value is actually the max number of chars).

Comment: I put it back to decimal(21,0) works fine.....just doesn't carry out the query as expected...

Comment: ok I solved it....answer was I had to do: $statement->bind_param("i", $user_id); never occurred to me that a decimal had to be binded as a string in mysqli...